# When i tried to build the code getting the "no instance of overloaded function matches the specified type"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Error (active)  E0493   no instance of overloaded function "NodeInfo::NodeInfo" matches the specified type.

In the below NodeInfo.cpp file am getting the error in the Constructor

```
NodeInfo.h

enum DataType { integer, floatNumber, string };
class NodeInfo
{
    DataType dataType;
    IntrusivePtr_t<NodeId_t> nodeId;

    std::string displayName;
    CString browsePath;
    CString dataValue;

public:
    CString GetNodeName();

};

NodeInfo.cpp

#include "NodeInfo.h"
NodeInfo::NodeInfo(IntrusivePtr_t<NodeId_t> _nodeId)
{
    nodeId = _nodeId;
}

CString NodeInfo::GetNodeName()
{
    CString strNodeNmae;

    return strNodeNmae;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to declare your constructor: `NodeInfo(IntrusivePtr_t<NodeId_t> _nodeId)` in the header file.

Comment: Thanks Man....Got it....I forgot add the constructor declaration in the .h file.